# update Kubernetes ingress version in helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, api-versioning

good day all, I want to know how I can update my Kubernetes ingress API version to networking.k8s.io/v1 in my helm chart template. will I use the kubectl apply command?

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
```

Comment: I don't think `kubectl` can do that, you might have to update manually

Comment: @Eugene thanks. pls what do you mean by manually?

Comment: can't you edit the file directly? create a new chart with that? or did I miss-understood your question?

Comment: @Eugene yes i can edit it directly, after editing it how do i apply it. using which helm command

Comment: this depends on a few things, but in general, you need [to package it](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_package/) and [install that chart](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_install/). Or you can install it directly (or upgrade), it depends if you are playing with this or this is a bigger architecture in place